# Wifi connection dropping and/or slow after upgrading to 14.10

Tags: wireless, upgrade, dell, 14.10, iwlwifi

I just recently upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10 and immediately started having issues with the wifi on my Dell XPS 13 laptop.  It'll work fine for a while (something like 30 min to an hour?) but then the connection starts to go slow (packet loss 25% to 75%) and then it eventually stops.  Sometimes it comes back on its own but most times I have to toggle the hardware wifi button (`fn + F2`).

When filtering logged messages for `iwlwifi`, seeing a possible error message `fail to flush all tx fifo queues Q 0` and multiple messages for `Q 4 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid`:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[ 9802.709772] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: fail to flush all tx fifo queues Q 0
[ 9802.709778] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Current SW read_ptr 81 write_ptr 84
[ 9802.709813] iwl data: 00000000: 00 00 0e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
[ 9802.709835] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(0) = 0x80003052
[ 9802.709856] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(1) = 0x801020a1
[ 9802.709868] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(2) = 0x00000000
[ 9802.709881] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(3) = 0x80300053
[ 9802.709893] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(4) = 0x00000000
[ 9802.709907] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(5) = 0x00000000
[ 9802.709921] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(6) = 0x00000000
[ 9802.709933] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(7) = 0x007090ef
[ 9802.709982] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 0 is active and mapped to fifo 3 ra_tid 0x0000 [81,84]
[ 9802.710031] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 1 is active and mapped to fifo 2 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710080] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 2 is active and mapped to fifo 1 ra_tid 0x0000 [146,199]
[ 9802.710128] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 3 is active and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [83,83]
[ 9802.710177] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 4 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710226] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 5 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710274] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 6 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710323] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 7 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710371] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 8 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710420] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 9 is active and mapped to fifo 7 ra_tid 0x0000 [240,240]
[ 9802.710469] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 10 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710517] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 11 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710566] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 12 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710614] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 13 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710663] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 14 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710712] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 15 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710761] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 16 is inactive and mapped to fifo 1 ra_tid 0x0000 [63,63]
[ 9802.710809] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 17 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710858] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 18 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 9802.710906] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 19 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
```

Some more info about my machine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 3.16.0-25-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 4 12:06:54 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ uname -r
3.16.0-25-generic

$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)
```

Not sure why having these issues now (Never had problems in the past when doing any release upgrades particularly with wifi)

Perhaps it thinks the laptop is idle/standby when it's not? I confirmed that the Power Management setting is off.

Not certain but seems to happen more frequently when using VPN.

Any thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a patch has been made to the kernel 3.16 to fix this wifi issue:

[Bug 56581 - iwlwifi iwldvm fail to flush Tx queue](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56581)

and is also being tracked as/linked to an Ubuntu bug:

[iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: fail to flush all tx fifo queues Q 2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1270808)

but [as of 11/11/2014 has not been yet been released as part of an Ubuntu update](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1270808/comments/14):

> Seth Forshee (sforshee) wrote on 2014-11-11:  #14
>
> The patch hasn't made it through to the released Ubuntu kernels yet.
>   I'll check on the status and try to accelerate the process if needed,
>   but it always takes several weeks for updates to get released due to
>   the amount of regression testing new kernels are subjected to before
>   they are released.

but [it's planned to be](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1270808/comments/17)

> Seth Forshee (sforshee) wrote on 2014-11-11:  #17
>
> I checked, and the patch is already queued for both trusty and utopic
>   in the next SRU cycle. This means that it won't be in the next kernel
>   update, but the one after that. The next update is already undergoing
>   regression testing so it is too late to get it in for the next kernel
>   update.

Unfortunately, I had to re-install the previous version of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (from 14.10) on my machine which resolved the issue with the wifi back to working as expected.  I plan to hold off upgrading until this bug has been fixed and released.